# directory listing denied

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Whenever I click on a hyperlink, I get an error that says "Directory Listing Denied". What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn on a feature in iis that enables directory listing. Check if this works http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(WS.10).aspx